# Is there a database of aircraft 3D models that are accurately created

Tags: aircraft-design

I was just wondering if there was such a thing as the title describes. I am trying to work on a machine learning algorithm that generates aircraft designs based on what it learns from current designs, where I think the appropriate dataset format is in 3D model form.

If there exists no such database/dataset, I think I might have to find each design plan of individual aircraft and extract as much information as I can (if that's even possible)

Comment: Have you checked out FlightGear flight simulator?

Comment: Good idea! Thank you. It seems I can download aircraft models...